# Advanced search: "is:answer" option matches question titles

Tags: support, search

I've been attempting to search SO for answers (and *only* answers) containing the string `plz` using the [Advanced Super Ninja Search Options](https://stackoverflow.com/search#).

The query I used is:

> [is:answer plz](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:answer%20plz)

However, the results returned were not what I expected:

[image: Screen grab of search]

Firstly, the results returned match **questions** where the string `plz` appears only in the title, and not in any of the answers. I've checked and none of the answers, comments, or anything else on those pages contain `plz` except the question title.

Secondly, the hyperlinks of those matched questions link me to **answers** on those questions, but as I said, those answers don't contain the `plz` string I searched for.

Examples of links returned by that search query:

- [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637763/postgis-postgres-geocoding-help-plz/6637861#6637861`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637763/postgis-postgres-geocoding-help-plz/6637861#6637861)
- [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981195/php-5-3-3-fails-to-validate-xml-against-nested-xsds-plz-help/5288415#5288415`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981195/php-5-3-3-fails-to-validate-xml-against-nested-xsds-plz-help/5288415#5288415)

My questions:

1. Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?
2. If this *is* [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) (and it seems strange to me if it is), is there any way to search just answer body text?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is definitely [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). While using `is:answer` will only give you answers, recall from the search help page (emphasis mine):

> … **Results are weighted heavily towards question title matches**, and any search terms matching the most popular 60 tags will be automatically mapped to a tag to help narrow your search.

Since answers don't have a "title", by default it retrieves matches hits to the question title. This is helpful for when you want to find a highly upvoted answer to a set of related questions.

---

Now to do what you want to do, you need to include the `body:` search option like so:

```
is:answer body:"plz"
```

This will give you hits for answers that contain the word "plz" in the body.

[image]

Comment: This appears to be broken by now, "body" no longer works. :/